# Proving the inequality of given function

Tags: inequality, continuity

Let define $\varphi(x)$ as follows:

$\varphi(x)= \begin{cases} 
x, & \text{if 0 $\le$ x $\le$ $\frac{1}{2}$} \\
1-x, & \text{if $\frac{1}{2}$ $\le$ x $\le$ 1} 
\end{cases}$

and extend this function to the entire real line as to have period 1.

We denote the extended function by $\varphi_0(x)$.

Further , let

$\varphi_n(x)$=$\frac{1}{4^n}\varphi_0(4^nx)$

I guess following inequality holds,

for every $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$\varphi_n(a+b)$ $\le$ $\varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)$.

Is it right? if not, could you give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: If $\varphi_n(x)=\frac{1}{4^n}\varphi_0(4^nx)$ so $\varphi_n(a+b)=\frac1{4^n}\varphi_0(4^n(a+b))$ and $\varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)=\frac1{4^n}(\varphi_0(4^na)+\varphi_0(4^nb))$

Secondly: let's define the following $\varphi_n(x):=\begin{cases}\frac1{4^n}[4^nx]&[4^nx]\in[0,0.5)\\\frac1{4^n}(1-[4^nx])&[4^nx]\in[0.5,1)\end{cases}$ where $[x]=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$(it is simply create the function periodically)

Now for every $c,d\in\Bbb R, a=4^nc,b=4^nd$ we have one of few options:\begin{cases}a,b,a+b&\text{are in case 1}\\a,b&\text{are in case 1 but $a+b$ ain't}\\a&\text{is in case 1 but $b,a+b$ ain't}\\a,a+b&\text{are in case 1 but $b$ ain't}\\a+b&\text{is in case 1 but $a,b$ ain't}\\a,b,a+b&\text{in case 2}\end{cases}

Now you can just check every one of the options, for example option 1:

$\varphi_n(c+d)=\frac1{4^n}[a+b]$, we know that $a,b<0.5$ hence $\frac1{4^n}[a+b]=\frac1{4^n}[a]+\frac1{4^n}[b]=\varphi_n(c)+\varphi_n(d)$ so in option 1 your statement is true

Comment: So it doesn't hold for every case?

Comment: and why there is a difference between case 1 and case 2? you define $\varphi_n(x)=1-[4^nx]$ of case 2 but case 1 has a factor of $\frac{1}{4^n}$, which is not included in case 2. Why they are different?

Comment: The way I defined $\varphi_n$ is exactly like you did but I did it shorter, if it confusing you, ignore it and look at the way you created $\varphi_n$

Comment: @Grimza you need to check every one of the options i stated above, if even for one of them your statement is false then $\varphi_n(a+b)\not\le\varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)$ for some $a,b,n$

Comment: @Grimza oh, I forgot, you are right, I'll edit it

Comment: thx:) I'll check those cases and let the result posted as soon as possible.

Comment: I've checked it. and it holds for every case.

Comment: @Grimza if it is hold of every case then $\varphi_n(a+b)\le \varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)$ for every $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $n\in\Bbb N$. You were right :). You should accept this answer

Comment: Btw, you have proven something even stronger, create the function $\Phi_n(a,b)=\varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)-\varphi_n(a+b)$ and try to plot it, see what you got

Answer (score 0):

The periodic function is given by for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$\varphi_0(x)= \begin{cases} 
x-k, & \text{if k $\le$ x $\le$ $k+\frac{1}{2}$} \\
k+1-x, & \text{if $k+\frac{1}{2}$ $\le$ x $\le$ k+1} 
\end{cases}$$
Also $$\varphi_n(x)=x\varphi_0(x)$$
Consider $a=\frac14,b=\frac14$ then $\varphi_n(1/2)=1/4$ and $\varphi_n(1/4)+\varphi_n(1/4)=1/8$. This would be a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. check please